# Can Entity History be enabled for ABP template?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, aspnetboilerplate

I downloaded ABP template from website:

- ABP v3.6.2
- MVC5
- MPA

I read how to enable Entity History and did these steps:

1. in **AppNameCoreModule.cs** `PreInitialize()` method, I add:

```
// Entity History
Configuration.EntityHistory.IsEnabled = true;
Configuration.EntityHistory.IsEnabledForAnonymousUsers = false;
Configuration.EntityHistory.Selectors.Add(
    new NamedTypeSelector(
        "Abp.FullAuditedEntities",
        type => typeof(IFullAudited).IsAssignableFrom(type)
    )
);
```

2. in **AppNameDbContext.cs**, I add:

```
// Entity History tables
public virtual DbSet<EntityChange> EntityChanges { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<EntityChangeSet> EntityChangeSets { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<EntityPropertyChange> EntityPropertyChanges { get; set; }
```

But the Entity History didn't work. Is there something wrong in my steps? And how to fix it?

Comment: You don't need to add DbSets to your DbContext. It's already in the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework 6x doesn't support Entity History. As far as I see you are adding the tables to your DbContext and you don't get exception. so you might be using MVC5 which has no Entity History support.

Answer (score 0):

The EntityHistory is available on EF 6.x https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Entity-History#entity-framework-6-x